# embedded function in .map to access mapped information

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using a .map function to display details to user.
I would like a button so that when it is clicked it expands for the user displaying more in depth information.

As it is mapped I cannot set a function as I would normally (between constructor and render)as it would not understand the mapped information e.g r.AssignedWorkStation

essentially I am asking is it possible to put a function within here (example below) and then have this be able to access the mapped properties

```
const renderTodos = currentTodos.map(r => {
      Test(){
        if(me){
          //function to do what I want 

        }

      }
      return (
        <>
          <div className="jumbotron">
            <button className="btn btn-primary" style={{ float: "right" }}>
              View Details
            </button>

            <br />
            <li>
              <b>Workstation : </b>

              {r.AssignedWorkStation}
            </li>
            <li>
              <b>Date: </b>
              {r.Date}
            </li>

            <li>
              <b>Status: </b>
              {r.CompleteToken}
            </li>

            <br />

          </div>
        </>
      );
    });
```

Whole class code

```
var results = [];
class AdminWorkstations extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      questions: [],
      viewDetails: false,

      currentPage: 1,
      todosPerPage: 4
    };
    this.getQuestionByUniqueDate = this.getQuestionByUniqueDate.bind(this);
    // this.test = this.test.bind(this);
  }
  // sets the questions form sql into state for questions
  handleClick = event => {
    this.setState({
      currentPage: Number(event.target.id)
    });
  };

  // test() {
  //   alert(r.AssignedWorkStation);
  // }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(`/admin-completed-workstations`)
      .then(recordset => recordset.json())
      .then(results => {
        this.setState({ questions: results.recordset });
        console.log(this.state.questions);

        this.state.questions &&
          this.getQuestionByUniqueDate(this.state.questions);
      });
  }

  handlePageChange(pageNumber) {
    this.setState({ activePage: pageNumber });
  }

  getQuestionByUniqueDate(questions) {
    for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
      if (
        !results.find(q => q.Date == questions[i].Date) ||
        !results.find(
          q => q.AssignedWorkStation == questions[i].AssignedWorkStation
        )
      ) {
        results.push(questions[i]);
        this.setState({ amountOfWorkstations: results.length });
      }
    }
    return results;
  }

  render() {
    const { currentPage, todosPerPage } = this.state;

    // Logic for displaying current todos
    const indexOfLastTodo = currentPage * todosPerPage;
    const indexOfFirstTodo = indexOfLastTodo - todosPerPage;
    const currentTodos = results.slice(indexOfFirstTodo, indexOfLastTodo);
    debugger;

    const renderTodos = currentTodos.map(r => {



      return (
        <>
          <div className="jumbotron">
            <button className="btn btn-primary" style={{ float: "right" }}>
              View Details
            </button>

            <br />
            <li>
              <b>Workstation : </b>

              {r.AssignedWorkStation}
            </li>
            <li>
              <b>Date: </b>
              {r.Date}
            </li>

            <li>
              <b>Status: </b>
              {r.CompleteToken}
            </li>

            <br />
            {/* <Questions results={r}></Questions> */}
          </div>
        </>
      );
    });
    const pageNumbers = [];
    for (
      let i = 1;
      i <= Math.ceil(this.state.amountOfWorkstations / todosPerPage);
      i++
    ) {
      pageNumbers.push(i);
    }

    const renderPageNumbers = pageNumbers.map(number => {
      return (
        <button
          className="btn btn-primary"
          key={number}
          id={number}
          onClick={this.handleClick}
        >
          {number}
        </button>
      );
    });

    let selectedWorkStation = window.localStorage.getItem("Workstation");

    console.log(this.state.questions);

    if (this.state.questions.length) {
      return (
        <div>
          <h2 style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
            Completed Workstation Assessments
          </h2>
          <ul>
            <button disabled className="btn btn-secondary">
              Workstation Assessments
            </button>
            <Link to="./admin-center">
              <button className="btn btn-secondary">Edit Questions</button>
            </Link>
            <Link to="./admin-center-view-users">
              <button className="btn btn-secondary">View Users</button>
            </Link>
            <DropdownButton
              style={{ float: "right" }}
              id="dropdown-basic-button"
              title="Completed"
            >
              <Dropdown.Item>
                {" "}
                <Link to="admin-view-workstation-assessments-declined">
                  In Progress
                </Link>
              </Dropdown.Item>
            </DropdownButton>{" "}
          </ul>

          <ul>
            {renderTodos}{" "}
            <div
              style={{ userSelect: "none", cursor: "pointer" }}
              id="page-numbers"
            >
              {renderPageNumbers}
            </div>
          </ul>
        </div>
      );
    } else if (!this.state.questions.length) {
      return (
        <>
          {" "}
          <div>
            <h3 style={{ textAlign: "center" }}></h3>

            <ul>
              <br />
              <br />{" "}
              <div>
                <h6>
                  {" "}
                  <tr>
                    Desk Location Selected :{" "}
                    <u style={{ color: "grey" }}>{selectedWorkStation}</u>
                  </tr>
                </h6>
              </div>
              <div className="jumbotron">
                <li style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                  <b>no completed Workstation Self-Assessments</b>{" "}
                </li>
              </div>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can set a function (between constructor and render) and pass `r` to it and access the mapped information, can you add relevant `class` code please ?

Comment: Have just added :)

Comment: Why don't you declare the function outside the map?  At the same level as renderTodos you could have the Test function as well.

Comment: @Taki I have tried that and used it as an onclick which when pressed sends an alert for evey workstation in in the array

Comment: @tudor.gergely is it wise to have that in a render function?

Comment: @henrypf You should avoid having functions inside your render function and especially inside your map call as JS will have to recreate the function every time. Define it at the class level.

Answer (score 1):

You should save your todos inside your component state, not compute it inside render.

You shouldn't have a global variable called results either, store that inside your component state as well.

Here is a small example:

```
fetch(`/admin-completed-workstations`)
      .then(recordset => recordset.json())
      .then(results => {
        this.setState({ questions: results.recordset });
        console.log(this.state.questions);

        // Here, inside getQuestionByUniqueDate you should store result using this.setState instead of having a global variable
        // Then you can simply move the entire renderTodo function outside the render function of this component
        this.state.questions &&
          this.getQuestionByUniqueDate(this.state.questions);
      });
```

LE: Here is a comprehensive article about fetching data in React.js apps:

https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-fetching-data (I recommend reading it)

LE2: You can assign both results and todos inside your componentDidMount

```
getQuestionByUniqueDate(questions) {
    const currentResults = this.state.results ? [...this.state.results] : [];
    for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
        if (
            !currentResults.find(q => q.Date == questions[i].Date) ||
            !currentResults.find(
                q => q.AssignedWorkStation == questions[i].AssignedWorkStation
            )
        ) {
            currentResults.push(questions[i]);
        }
    }
    return currentResults;
}


fetch(`/admin-completed-workstations`)
    .then(recordset => recordset.json())
    .then(res => {
        const results = res.recordset &&
            this.getQuestionByUniqueDate(res.recordset);
        // Logic for displaying current todos
        const indexOfLastTodo = currentPage * todosPerPage;
        const indexOfFirstTodo = indexOfLastTodo - todosPerPage;
        const currentTodos = results.slice(indexOfFirstTodo, indexOfLastTodo);
        this.setState({
            questions: res.recordset,
            results,
            currentTodos,
            amountOfWorkstations: results.length
        });
    });
```

Comment: I have now made it so that results are saved in state but how would I get it so that the todos are out of the render? An example would be great

Comment: Can you update your question with the new results inside state? And I'll help you with an example in a bit

Comment: does the fetch not need to be within a method already ? like component did mount etc

Comment: Gave it a go it didn't work. Firstly I am fairly sure fetch should be in a method not stand alone and so to try and amend this I put it within my component did mount function.Then there was many things withing this fetch which were not defined.

Comment: Thankyou for the help though

Comment: those were just examples, I did not write your entire class there. Of course fetch needs to be in a methods, I just changed a few lines/methods to give you an example. Keep in mind that I don't know how you API works though